# AWS Java - Referencing file included in my .War package not found

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, war

I need this file to authorize my API request to an external service. My app is deployed in Elastic Beanstalk with a WAR package and my file is stored in WEB-INF/lib but when I route my service to this address nothing is happening. My java classes are stored in WEB-INF/classes and its subfolders (due to packages). Should I use any absolute address instead of a relative one? Any ideas about what may be happening?

My build.xml file to generate War package with ant:

[image]

Comment: How are you building your project?

Comment: @smac2020 With ant and its build.xml file. I'll post it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing dependencies. I have never seen this issue when building a web app using Spring BOOT and Maven. As well, when building with Maven/Spring BOOT, I always ensure to use **spring-boot-maven-plugin** that builds an executable JAR file which includes the dependencies.

TO learn how to create a basic Java app with Dependencies and deploy to the Elastic Beanstalk, see this AWS tutorial.

[Creating your first AWS Java web application](https://github.com/scmacdon/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_first_project)

Comment: Okey, I'll try it but then how should I refer my file in the java code? like "./WEB-INF/lib/<file>"? Thanks

Comment: I recommend doing some tests. For example, see if your WAR runs fine on a local server like Tomcat. I have seen ANT do funny things, one of the reason why i prefer Maven.